# To continously check for the signal in Android and then launch the app

Tags: android, mobile

I'm working on a project that receives a signal on Android via Bluetooth when car engine ignites. Once Android receives signal the mobile will go for silent mode and disconnect all the calls and then sends msg to the caller.

The problem I'm facing is that, Android mobile should search for the signal continuously, and once it receives it should launch the app which I have coded. How to check for the signal continuously? Do I have to use Service concept of Android? How to use that?

I'm new to Android.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: Thank you.. Its now working... I m very happy. I tried it for ginger bread. Its working. But when i tried for jellybean, it failed. I have also mentioned the target version as 4.2. Everything except receiving bluetooth signal is working fine. Something is wrong with bluetooth part . please help me so that it works for 4.2 too . Its very necessary. Thank u in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Service to listen to bluetooth. You will not be able to disconnect calls.